# How to navigate from swift UI to storyboard on button click in swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, storyboard

I am working on an app that has both swiftUI and storyboard. I have a button in swift UI. On click of this I need to navigate to a storyboard screen. I tried the below code but it is not getting called. Kindly help....

in my swiftUI, the button code is as below,

```
    Button(action:{ TestController()
                                    
                                }, label:
                                    {
                                        Text("Click me").foregroundColor(.white)
                                        Image(systemName: "chevron.forward.2").imageScale(.large)})



struct TestController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "test", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "testView")
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
       
    }
}
```

Please help me...

Comment: "I tried the below code but it is not getting called"  Firstly, the word below is not an adjective.  Secondly, WHAT is not getting called?

Comment: I believe you should be using `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`, but I'm not sure if that's the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavigationLink` with `NavigationView`

```
struct MyTestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: TestController(),
                label: {
                    Text("Click me").foregroundColor(.white)
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.forward.2").imageScale(.large)}
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There may be different ways of doing it. But my requirement was this.... As it is existing code and cannot change the UI elements due to old functionality

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution over here,

[How to show NavigationLink as a button in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130866/how-to-show-navigationlink-as-a-button-in-swiftui)

This works perfectly,

```
Button(action: {
    print("Floating Button Click")
}, label: {
    NavigationLink(destination: AddItemView()) {
         Text("Open View")
     }
})
```

Comment: Why not use a direct navigation line ???? No need Button.