# Go to SwiftUi View File "Home" with button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to go to my SwiftUi View File ***Home*** by clicking my button in iOS 16:

[image: Screenshot]

I already read Apple documentation and searched in Google and YouTube but I didn't got the answer.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Welcome To").font(.system(size: 45)).fontWeight(.heavy).foregroundColor(.primary)
            Text("Pumping Fitness").font(.system(size: 45)).fontWeight(.heavy).gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .yellow])
            Spacer()
            
            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
                
                
                HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 20)
                {
                    Image(systemName: "dumbbell.fill").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 30).gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .orange])
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                        Text("Track your workouts").bold().font(.system(size: 22)).padding(.top, 10.0)
                        
                        Text("Easily track your progress during you are working out").font(.subheadline).padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                    }
                }
                
                
                HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 20)
                {
                    Image(systemName: "timer").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40).gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .orange])
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                        Text("Auto rest timer").bold().font(.system(size: 22))
                        
                        Text("Start your rest time with one single tap").font(.subheadline).padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                    }
                }
                
                
                HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 20)
                {
                    Image(systemName: "figure.run").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 50).gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .orange])
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                        Text("Add your own exercises").bold().font(.system(size: 22))
                        
                        Text("Create your own type of exercises at a glance").font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
            
            //HStack creado para poder alinear el boton al centro.
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Button(action: {} ) {
                        Text("Start Pumping").fontWeight(.black).foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 280, height: 60)
                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.yellow]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                .cornerRadius(17)
                
            }.padding(.leading)
        }.padding(.all, 40)
        
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}


extension View {
    public func gradientForeground(colors: [Color]) -> some View {
        self.overlay(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: colors), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .topTrailing))
            .mask(self)
    }
}
```

Do you know how can I do it? All the YouTube videos I saw were using a list, and I want to show this "welcome page" then go to my home page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show NavigationLink as a button in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130866/how-to-show-navigationlink-as-a-button-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code a bit. Use ContentView as your module for navigationStack. Separate ContentView code to WelcomeView and use it as Follows:

```
struct WelcomeView: View {
@Binding var gotoSomewhere: Bool // I recommend you to read some articles about @Sate and @Binding property wrappers

var body: some View {
    
    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Welcome To").font(.system(size: 45)).fontWeight(.heavy).foregroundColor(.primary)
        Text("Pumping Fitness").font(.system(size: 45)).fontWeight(.heavy).gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .yellow])
        Spacer()
        
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
            
            
            HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 20)
            {
                Image(systemName: "dumbbell.fill").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 30).gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .orange])
                
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    Text("Track your workouts").bold().font(.system(size: 22)).padding(.top, 10.0)
                    
                    Text("Easily track your progress during you are working out").font(.subheadline).padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                }
            }
            
            
            HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 20)
            {
                Image(systemName: "timer").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40).gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .orange])
                
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    Text("Auto rest timer").bold().font(.system(size: 22))
                    
                    Text("Start your rest time with one single tap").font(.subheadline).padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                }
            }
            
            
            HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 20)
            {
                Image(systemName: "figure.run").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 50).gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .orange])
                
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    Text("Add your own exercises").bold().font(.system(size: 22))
                    
                    Text("Create your own type of exercises at a glance").font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        
        //HStack creado para poder alinear el boton al centro.
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Tap Tap")
                    gotoSomewhere = true
                } ) {
                    Text("Start Pumping").fontWeight(.black).foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 280, height: 60)
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.yellow]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
            .cornerRadius(17)
            
        }.padding(.leading)
    }.padding(.all, 40)
    
}
}
```

Then update your contentView with NavigationStack like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {

@State var gotoHomePage: Bool = false // this is important
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    WelcomeView(gotoSomewhere: $gotoHomePage)
                    NavigationLink(isActive: $gotoHomePage) {
                        HomeView() // This is your Home View you want to navigate to
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) // if you want a back button then pass false or comment this modifier
                    } label: {
                        EmptyView()
                    }

                }
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                
            }
    
    
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works! But shows me an alert in `NavigationLink(isActive: $goToHome)` of contentView. The alert is: ***'init(isActive:destination:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView*** and I'm looking how to fix this alert fro iOS 16

Comment: @MoiesBautista, use this code: `NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                WelcomeView(gotoSomewhere: $gotoHomePage)
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $gotoHomePage) {
                HomeView()
                    
            }
}`

Comment: Thanks! it disappeared the alert of iOS 16

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use a navigation stack, then you'd want to wrap your `View` `body` inside a `NavigationView`. If you're targeting iOS 16+ you should use `NavigationStack` instead (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types). Hacking with Swift also has an [article on `NavigationStack`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-push-a-new-view-onto-a-navigationstack).

There is some more useful info on `NavigationView` on the [Hacking with Swift blog here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui), as well as other resources you should be able to find online. There are some examples there you could use in your situations such as:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingDetailView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View"), isActive: $isShowingDetailView) { EmptyView() }
                Button("Tap to show detail") {
                    self.isShowingDetailView = true
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
        }
    }
}
```

This question is pretty similar: [How to show NavigationLink as a button in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130866/how-to-show-navigationlink-as-a-button-in-swiftui)

Comment: Apple recommends to use the newer `NavigationStack` instead of the now deprecated `NavigationView`.

Comment: Good point. Added some more info, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do it with NavigationStack but I can't